# tcp and udp echoclient server using select

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, network-programming, udp

here is code snippet for tcp and udp echoclient server using select.i had done with poll and 
got a good clarity but when coming to select it had described in the book i.e in the below code snippet we should take **(maxpl+2)** i did not got it and first of all why we are taking max(tcp_sfd,udp_sfd)?

```
 fd_set fdvar; 
 FD_ZERO(&fdvar); 
 FD_SET(tcp_sfd,&fdvar); 
 FD_SET(udp_sfd,&fdvar); 
 int maxpl = max(tcp_sfd,udp_sfd); 
 cout << "Waiting for a client...\n";

 if(select(maxpl+2 ,&fdvar,NULL,NULL,NULL)==-1) 
 { 
      perror("error in select"); 
  } 
 if(FD_ISSET(udp_sfd,&fdvar)) 
 { 
      // UDP 
  } 
  else 
  { 
      //TCP 
  }
```

Comment: Can you clarify: what exactly is the question ?

Comment: if(select(maxpl+2 ,&fdvar,NULL,NULL,NULL)==-1) 
 { 
      perror("error in select"); 
  } in the select statement why he is taking (maxpl+2) and in the code snippet why it was  max(tcpsocketsfd,udpsocketsfd)?

Comment: can you post the full code instead of the snippet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the shown code here, `maxpl+2` is wrong, it should be `maxpl+1`, although using `maxpl+2` is harmless.

`select` needs its 1. argument to be 1 greater than tne value of the largest file descriptor you have in either of your `fd_set`'s. - because that's what the documentation for select says it must be.

Comment: a small doubt when the two sockets are created i.e tcp socket and udp socket what does maxpl=max(tcp_fd,udp_sfd) mean in taking in the select statement?

Comment: @user1670364 As mentioned, select needs the 1. argument to be 1 greater than the largest file descriptor value. If you have two file descripors, you use max(tcp_fd,udp_sfd)  to find which of them is the largest.

Answer (score 0):

from man page:

The nfds argument specifies the range of descriptors to be tested.  The first nfds descriptors shall be checked  in  each  set;
that is, the descriptors from zero through nfds-1 in the descriptor sets shall be examined.

the first argument of select should be the max of all the fds in it, plus one.